# Мерджинг в мастер бренчу

Tags: git

Мы делали рефакторинг и теперь хотим слить ветку рефакторинг в мастер
 но при этом возникает очень много конфликтов, какое лучшее решение в этой ситуации?
Можно ли заменять мастер ветку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неясно, что вы вкладываете в понятие "заменять мастер-ветку", но ветка "мастер" ничем не отличается от любой другой ветки. Просто так сложилось исторически, что основную релизную ветку называют master. Ее можно назвать и по-другому, равно как и ветки с таким именем вообще может и не быть (на гитхабе есть проекты без ветки master). Так что можете ничего никуда не вливать, а просто назначить релизной веткой ветку, где делали рефакторинг.